# (ruby) help matching my regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match the value of the following HTML snippet:

```
<input name="example" type="hidden" value="matchTextHere" />
```

with the following:

```
x = response.match(/<input name="example" type="hidden" value="^.+$" \/>/)[0]
```

why is this not working? it doesn't match 'matchTextHere'

**edit:**

when i use:

```
x = response.match(/<input name="example" type="hidden" value="(.+)" \/>/)[0]
```

it matches the whole html element, and not just the value 'matchTextHere'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` matches start of a line and `$` matches end of the line. Change `^.+$` to `\w+` and it will work for values that doesn't contain any symbols. Make it a parenthetical group to capture the value - `(\w+)`

Update: to match anything between the quotes (assuming that there aren't any quotes in the value), use `[^"]+`. If there are escaped quotes in the value, it is a different ballgame. `.+` will work in this case, but it will be slower due to backtracking. `.+` first matches upto the end of the string (because `.` matches even a `"`), then looks for a `"` and fails. Then it comes back one position and looks for a `"` and fails again - and so on until it finds the `"` - if there was one more attribute after `value`, then you will get `matchTextHere" nextAttr="something` as the match.

```
x = response.match(/<input name="example" type="hidden" value="([^"]+)" \/>/)[1]
```

That being said, the regex will fail if there is an extra space between any of the attribute values. Parsing html with regex is not a good idea - and if you must use regex, you can allow extra spaces using `\s+`

```
/<input\s+name="example"\s+type="hidden"\s+value="([^"]+)"\s*\/>/
```

Comment: i need to match letters, symbols and numbers. basically i need to match anything that's in between the quotes there.

Comment: use `[^"]+` to capture symbols

Comment: /<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="[^"]+" \/>/ returns the entire string as well, not the value i want

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a start-of-line token (`^`) and an end-of-line token (`$`) in your regular expression. I think you meant to capture the value, this might solve your problem: `value="(.+?)"`.

Beware, though, that processing html with regular expressions is not a good idea, it can even [drive you crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Better use an [html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+html+parser) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ^ and $:

```
x = response.match(/<input name="example" type="hidden" value=".+" \/>/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change [0] to [1]

```
response='<input name="example" type="hidden" value="matchTextHere" />'

puts response.match(/<input name="example" type="hidden" value="(.*?)" \/>/)[1]

matchTextHere
```